# Why I am I getting additional data as response back in my ajax call from my server?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, codeigniter-3

Here is my code

```
$url = 'https://'.$_ENV["MAIL_CHIMP_DC"] .'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$_ENV["MAIL_CHIMP_LIST_ID"].'/members';
    error_log('url-mail_chimp');
    error_log($url);
    $authorization_header=base64_encode('anystring:'.$_ENV['MAIL_CHIMP_API_KEY']);
    error_log($authorization_header);
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    $data_string = $data;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json','Authorization:Basic '.$authorization_header));
    $result =curl_exec($ch);
    error_log($result);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    error_log($httpcode);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'hello';
```

This is all inside a controller which is being called on ajax call. But when I am doing `console.log(data)` on jquery `success` handler, I am getting full response which is being sent over by curl request and also "hello" is appended to that response. I don't know how the response is being sent.

Comment: Try this see what you get `$result = curl_exec($ch); echo $result ; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to your curl call. Without this, `curl_exec` will not return the response of the call as a string but will output it directly. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt) for `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it directly.

So, add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

to your code and the output should be correctly returned into your `$result` variable.